# The inner working of #defines that call methods

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

I know that defines in the beginning of a C++ file are [Preprocessor directives](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/preprocessor/) so "the preprocessor is executed before the actual compilation of code begins, therefore the preprocessor digests all these directives before any code is generated by the statements [1]".

Now what if I have this simple example:

```
#define PRINT(function) printFnctionName(#function)

void printFnctionName(string name)
{
    cout << name;
}

void test(){};
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    PRINT(test);
}
```

So now my question is really how does the precompiler know what function will be passed in? and how is the pre-compilation/linking/compilation really happening?

Also, the reason I am using define and not a regular function, it is because I wasn't able to find a way to replicate this functionality `#function to retrieve the name of a function

Comment: Maybe you are looking for `__func__` ? It's a predefined `const char[]` variable that contains the name of the current function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So now my question is really how does the precompiler know what
>   function will be passed in? and how is the
>   pre-compilation/linking/compilation really happening?

Preprocessor doesn't know about anything. It simply replaces the text with the defined value and stringifies the value you passed in.

So the compiler sees it:

```
void printFnctionName(string name)
{
    cout << name;
}

void test(){};
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printFnctionName("test");
}
```

Comment: I think a part here is missing: `#function` will add quotes - so if `function` is `test`, then `#function` becomes `"test"`.

Answer (score 1):

The preprocessor does text substitution. In your case, your code will be transformed to:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printFnctionName("test");
}
```

by the preprocessor *before* the rest of the compiling process kicks in. Some preprocessor directives are simple, other much more complicated (variable arity preprocessor directives, for instance).

Of course, it requires that you have included the correct header file etc.

Answer (score 0):

For this particular case, there are two parts to the answer. One part is that C preprocessor knows nothing about what function is being called, it simply does the textual replacement.

The second part is the "stringifier", `#function` actually replaces `test` as an input to `PRINT` with `"test"`. Of course, it doesn't have to be a function - just because it's called printfunction, you could do:

```
 PRINT(a+b);
```

and you'd get the code:

```
 printFnctionName("a+b");
```

or

```
 PRINT(a-*&1,78^%j)
```

and get:

```
 printFnctionName("a-*&1,78^%j");
```

[Why is the `u` missining in printFnctionName?]

The stringification operator is very useful if you have something like

```
#define ASSERT(x) do { if (!x) fail_assert(#x, __FILE__, __LINE__); } while(0)

void fail_assert(const char *expr, const char *file, int line)
{
     cerr << "Assertion (" << expr << ") failed at " << file << ":" << line << endl;
}

.... 

ASSERT(ptr != NULL);
```

Now you get an error message "Assertion failed (ptr != NULL) at myprog.cpp:112", which can be quite useful.